# How to create Managed DirectX Sprite that matches behavior of passing null to Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font.DrawText()

Tags: c#, directx-9

I am attempting to improve the directx performance of a well tested working application.  Using a profile tool, I have pinpointed that a call to Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font.DrawText(Sprite sprite, string text, int x, int y, int color) with null passed for the sprite parameter is responsible for approximately 30% of the application's CPU usage.  When I create a sprite and pass it to all calls of DrawText the CPU usage is close to eliminated.  The only problem is the font gets really small and rotated in a way that isn't legible.

Can anyone create a sprite that will render text in the same way that passing null to Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font.DrawText(Sprite sprite, string text, int x, int y, int color) does?  I know there are ways to use 2D text instead of what I have but would prefer to avoid making big changes to this working app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the draw calls between `Sprite.Begin()` and `Sprite.End()`. The `Begin()` call will apply appropriate render states (e.g. transformations) and the `End()` call restores the previous state. Of course, you should not draw anything other than sprites within this block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I also added this line of code to reset the Sprite of prior transforms.  Sprite.Transform = Matrix.Identity;